# Downgrading Node version in NVM Permanently

Tags: nodes, nvm

I need to downgrade my node version in my ubuntu local environtment.

[image]

I have to use `nvm use (version)` lately to downgrade, but whenever i open a new terminal it always return to the default state.

It's not effective for me whenever i need to build my lower environtment project.

Please help me to make my life easier.

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my version answer

1. Do below script to make your older version to be the default nvm

> nvm alias default 12.14.1

2. Select Your version with below syntax

> nvm use 12.14.1

3. Check your current node version

> node -v

You can check it again with

> node -v

after restart the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Please do these steps:

**1. Make the installed version default**

> nvm alias default 12.14.1

**2. Use Your version with below syntax**

> nvm use 12.14.1

**3. Check your node version**

> node -v

Thank you